# Call to function 'ABRecordCopyValue' returns a corefoundation object with a +1 retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I have following code in my project

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    [popContactsForm dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    [ssemailvc setName: (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];        
    ABMultiValueRef emails = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonEmailProperty);


    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0) {
        [ssemailvc setEmail:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails,0)];
    }else [ssemailvc setEmail:@""];

    CFRelease(emails);


    [peoplePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];      
    [popEmailForm setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350.0, 225.0)];

    return NO;
}
```

I am gettings following warnings

> 1.call to function 'ABRecordCopyValue' returns a corefoundation object with a +1 retain count
>   2.object leaked:allocated object is not referenced later in the execution and has a retain count of +1

Please tell me how to overcome this problem

Comment: No.I am not using ARC

Comment: Did you gave a try to any of the 2 answers posted below ?

Comment: I have converted code to ARC:  [ssemailvc setName: (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];        
    ABMultiValueRef emails = (__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonEmailProperty));
    
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0) {
        [ssemailvc setEmail:(__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails,0)];
    }else [ssemailvc setEmail:@""];
    
    CFRelease(emails); But still it is showing the same issue

Comment: 1. You should accept justin's answer. 2. You should repeat the `CFRelease` process for the email you retrieve via `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex`, too. 3. Your cast of `emails` to a `NSString *` is incorrect and you should just remove that cast.

Answer (score 6):

If using ARC, you can use a bridge cast:

```
CFStringRef name = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
[ssemailvc setName:(__bridge NSString*)name];
CFRelease(name);
```

or a bridge transfer:

```
NSString * name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
[ssemailvc setName:name];
```

---

If you are using MRC:

```
CFStringRef name = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
[ssemailvc setName:(NSString*)name];
CFRelease(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing the warning is that `ABRecordCopyValue` returns a `CFStringRef` with `+1 retain count`.

Try

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

[popContactsForm dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

CFStringRef strLname = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
[ssemailvc setName: (NSString *) strLname];  

if(strLname){
CFRelease(strLname);
}

ABMultiValueRef emails = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonEmailProperty);


if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0) {
    [ssemailvc setEmail:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails,0)];
}else [ssemailvc setEmail:@""];

if(emails){
CFRelease(emails);
}

[peoplePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];      
[popEmailForm setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350.0, 225.0)];

return NO;
}
```